# Destroying App component after running tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i am developing a angular website and i have a problem while running unit tests. I have my app component like this

```
export class Appcomponent {
    constructor(private service: SomeService) {
        service.init()
    }
}
```

and the init() method of the service has

```
init() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.http.get(' /api/configuration/v1/log').map(res=> res).subscribe(() => {});
    }, 30000)
}
```

Now the problem is that , when i run unit tests like this,

```
describe('Appapponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let app: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(
      {
        declarations: APP_DECLARATIONS,
        imports: APP_IMPORTS,
        providers: [APP_PROVIDERS, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]
      }
    ).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    expect(app).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

When i run the tests, tests run properly but the http call keeps on going because of set interval and the tests won't exit. as shown below

[image]

Because of this the build gets timeout and fails. How to resolve this issue ? Please help me.

**Edit**

COnfivguration added

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false
        },
        files: [
            { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'] },
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: false,
        captureTimeout: 200000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 2000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 200000
    });
};
```

Comment: can you add the configuration file

Comment: unit tests are not supposed to call external dependencies like APIs. That call should be mocked.

Comment: Okay even if it is mocked, the setINterval will b present and will go on a loop again right ?

Comment: Hey Aravind, i have added the configurations as wel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What I Want to Know

```
 this.http.get(' /api/configuration/v1/log').map(res=> res).subscribe(() => {});
```

Why are  you using that code and what is the use of it. I think that code is doing nothing. Please make sure this code is really want to your application???.

---

### Problem

> But anyway come to the point. Why are you using `$http` service call inside the `controller.component`? It should be written in inside of `service.componenet` section. because then only you can write `mock service` instead of real service while unit testing.

### So, What you want to do in UI unit Testing

You should move this `$http` call into a service class, like

```
export class SomeService{
    constructor(private http: $http) {

    }    
   get()
    {
      setInterval(() => {
      this.http.get(' /api/configuration/v1/log').map(res=> 
      res).subscribe(() => {});
    }, 30000)
  }
}
```

- ***Then you should write this same `get()` method with returning mock data in a `Mock Service class`.***

like,

```
    export class MockSomeService{
    constructor(private http: $http) {            
    }    
    get()
    {
     return Observable.of({});   //{} send mock data which you want to be check          
    }
 }
```

- ***And pass that mock class instead of real class via providers while configuring your test component.***

like,

```
providers: [{ provide: SomeService, useClass: MockSomeService}]
```

> Now the real service has been mocked while testing. So you can get the mock data instead of `real data/real service call` to check the test case expectation.

---

### Solution for SetTimout() issue

Normally if you are using `Settimeout()` function in your `controller.componenet`. You need to add this below line of code next to the `fixture.detectChanges();` in test cases.

```
        tick(3000);
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(0).toEqual(0);// do your expectation 
        });
```

Comment: That method basically posts data to the server every 30 sec.

Comment: THis works fine ,, but shouldn't the component be destroyed after running the test . Why is it not getting destroying . Any idea ?

Comment: @VikhyathMaiya Why you want to check that in unit test. You need check it only once with the mock data... Unless your unit test will be end less..